# Is it possible to create a single table for each model instance in Django?

Tags: django, database, foreign-keys, relationship

I have a model called Schedule. A single schedule is a big table with 3 columns and maybe 500 rows. So, whenever a user saves an instance of a schedule, it needs to create a new table for that schedule only.

This is not just specific to Django, how do you handle this in a database ?

Comment: Why does it need to create a new table? 500 rows isn't very many.

Comment: I'm confused in one thing? Is it efficient to store all those in one table ? Or is it efficient to assign single table to each instance because each instance is itself a table ?

Comment: How many users? How many schedules per user? Databases can easily handle millions of rows. 500 rows per user is nothing. It depends how you query, if you index your rows properly there shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Yeah just made a many to one relationship. Was just wondering if there was a better way to handle it. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to your Schedule model, you can also add a ScheduleRow model, something like:

```
class ScheduleRow(models.Model):
    schedule = models.ForeignKey(Schedule, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    row_number = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    column_1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    column_2 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    column_3 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

You can still store metadata for each schedule in the Schedule model, but the data rows are best stored as ScheduleRows.

Comment: Yeah that is what I did. Thanks.